# My Intellij worksheet does not print out the number sequence defined in Thread.run, but sbt does

Tags: multithreading, scala, intellij-idea

I tried the following code in an Intellij worksheet:

```
val hello = new Thread(new Runnable {
  def run() {
    for (i<-1 to 10) print(i,",")
  }
})
hello.start()
```

The output I got is

```
hello: Thread = Thread[Thread-111,5,main]
```

I would expect to also get something like "1 2 3 ...10". Why does not my Intellij print the number sequence? Below is the screenshot from my Intellij.

[image]

VERY SURPRISINGLY, if I put the same code in sbt console, I got the results:

```
scala> val hello = new Thread(new Runnable {
     |   def run() {
     |     for (i<-1 to 10) print(i,",")
     |   }
     | })
hello: Thread = Thread[Thread-5,5,run-main-group-0]

scala> hello.start()
(1,,)(2,,)(3,,)(4,,)(5,,)(6,,)(7,,)(8,,)(9,,)(10,,)
scala>
```

Comment: Your code works in IntelliJ no problem. You just have to join the thread back to the console: `hello.join()` The IntelliJ worksheet doesn't like to report output from detached threads: `concurrent.Future(println("HERE"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. your code doesn't wait till thread is finished
2. print treats
   parameter as a tuple and prints:
   (1,,)(2,,)(3,,)(4,,)(5,,)(6,,)(7,,)(8,,)(9,,)(10,,)

Something like this should work (I didn't try to run it IntelliJ though, just in Scala console

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val hello = new Thread(new Runnable {
  def run() {
    println((1 to 10).mkString(","))
  }
})
hello.start()
hello.join()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
hello: java.lang.Thread = Thread[Thread-10,5,]

scala>
```